# values changes (avoid 0 1 to 1 2)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to transform factor to numeric  to be able to take the mean of it as.numeric changes the value, numeric doesn't work.

```
mtcars$vec <- factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

        num.cols <- c("vec" ) 
        mtcars[num.cols] <- lapply(mtcars[num.cols], as.numeric) 
        str(mtcars)

        mtcars$vec
```

expected results should be numeric and consist of only 0 and 1

```
mtcars$vec
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: `mtcars$vec <- as.numeric(as.character(mtcars$vec))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to convert to character and then to `numeric` because if we directly apply `as.numeric`, it gets coerced to the integer storage values instead of the actual values which starts from 1.  In this case, there is a confusion because the values are binary

```
mtcars[num.cols] <-  lapply(mtcars[num.cols], 
              function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) 
mtcars$vec
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Or a faster option is also

```
mtcars[num.cols] <- lapply(mtcars[num.cols],  function(x) as.numeric(levels(x)[x]))
```

If it is a single column, we can do this more easily

```
mtcars[[num.cols]] <- as.numeric(levels(mtcars[[num.cols]])[mtcars[[num.cols]]])
```

---

As an example

```
v1 <- factor(c(15, 15, 3, 3))
as.numeric(v1)
#[1] 2 2 1 1

as.numeric(as.character(v1))
#[1] 15 15  3  3
```